# Adding accounts through Android Account Manager

Tags: android

I have a requirement to add google account to Android Account Manager.I tried using Account Manager's addAccountExplicitly API.But it throws a security exception saying

```
java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid xxxxx is different than the authenticator's uid
```

Also, I tried using addAccount API But I got the google account log in Dialog.I dont want this dailog even.

Is it possible to add google account specifying username and password.so that account get added directly into Account Manager without any user actions?

Many Thanks

Bhavani

Comment: For answering this question it is important to know what are you trying to do?

Comment: we are just having requiremnt to set up default accounts for Google, twitter, facebook Applications.

Comment: Our application will configure default accounts for google, FB and Twitter Application.For this, am trying to add google account to account manager programmatically using username and password

Comment: Then you are **stuck** with the dialog. You do not get to create accounts for other account managers without sharing the user identifier (i.e. either using a sharedUsedId in both & signing the applications with the same certificate or putting your code in the same app as the authenticator).